# Extract text between two P's

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the data between two elements "Executives" and "Analysts", [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy6eo.png), but i don't know how to proceed. 
My html is:

```
<div class="content_part hid" id="article_participants">
<p>Wabash National Corporation (NYSE:<a title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/wnc">WNC</a>)</p><p>Q4 2014 <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: yellow;">Earnings</span> Conference <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: rgb(243, 134, 134);">Call</span></p><p>February 04, 2015 10:00 AM ET</p>
<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Mike Pettit - Vice President of Finance and Investor Relations</p>
<p>Richard Giromini - President and Chief Executive Officer</p>
<p>Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</p>
<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>
```

I want to do this for a whole bunch of files my code till this far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import textwrap
import os
from lxml import html
import csv

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            page=f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
            match = soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_participants')
    print(match)
```

I am a newby in Python, so bear with me.

My prefered output would be:
[image: Example output]

Headline can be found in the following HTML:

```
<div class="page_header_email_alerts" id="page_header">
      <h1>
        <span itemprop="headline">Wabash National's (WNC) CEO Richard Giromini on Q4 2014 Results - Earnings Call Transcript</span>
              </h1>

      <div id="article_info">
        <div class="article_info_pos">
          <span itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-04T21:48:03Z">Feb.  4, 2015  4:48 PM ET</span>
          <span id="title_article_comments"></span>
          <span class="print_hide"><span class="print_hide">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span> <span>About:</span> <span id="about_primary_stocks"><a title="Wabash National Corporation" href="/symbol/WNC" sasource="article_primary_about_trc">Wabash National Corporation (WNC)</a></span></span>
          <span class="author_name_for_print">by: SA Transcripts</span>
            <span id="second_line_wrapper"></span>
        </div>
'''
```

Comment: The image you posted is super blurry, could you post an html code snippet in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your code.

```
import os
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if filename.endswith('.html'):
    fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
      page=f.read()
      doc = SimplifiedDoc(page)
      headline = doc.select('div#article_info>span#about_primary_stocks>a>text()')
      div = doc.select('div#article_participants')
      if not div: continue
      ps = div.getElements('p',start='<strong>Executives</strong>',end='<strong>Analysts</strong>')
      Executives = [p.text.split('-')[0].strip() for p in ps]
      ps = div.getElements('p',start='<strong>Analysts</strong>')
      Analysts = [p.text.split('-')[0].strip() for p in ps]
      print (headline)
      print (Executives)
      print (Analysts)
```

The following code is an example.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div class="page_header_email_alerts" id="page_header">
  <h1>
    <span itemprop="headline">Wabash National's (WNC) CEO Richard Giromini on Q4 2014 Results - Earnings Call Transcript</span>
  </h1>
  <div id="article_info">
    <div class="article_info_pos">
      <span itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-04T21:48:03Z">Feb.  4, 2015  4:48 PM ET</span>
      <span id="title_article_comments"></span>
      <span class="print_hide"><span class="print_hide">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span> <span>About:</span> <span id="about_primary_stocks"><a title="Wabash National Corporation" href="/symbol/WNC" sasource="article_primary_about_trc">Wabash National Corporation (WNC)</a></span></span>
      <span class="author_name_for_print">by: SA Transcripts</span>
        <span id="second_line_wrapper"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_part hid" id="article_participants">
<p>Wabash National Corporation (NYSE:<a title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/wnc">WNC</a>)</p><p>Q4 2014 <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: yellow;">Earnings</span> Conference <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: rgb(243, 134, 134);">Call</span></p><p>February 04, 2015 10:00 AM ET</p>
<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Mike Pettit - Vice President of Finance and Investor Relations</p>
<p>Richard Giromini - President and Chief Executive Officer</p>
<p>Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</p>
<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>
<p>Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</p>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
headline = doc.select('div#article_info>span#about_primary_stocks>a>text()')
div = doc.select('div#article_participants')
ps = div.getElements('p',start='<strong>Executives</strong>',end='<strong>Analysts</strong>')
Executives = [p.text.split('-')[0].strip() for p in ps]
ps = div.getElements('p',start='<strong>Analysts</strong>')
Analysts = [p.text.split('-')[0].strip() for p in ps]

print (headline)
print (Executives)
print (Analysts)
```

Result:

```
Wabash National Corporation (WNC)
[u'Mike Pettit', u'Richard Giromini', u'Jeffery Taylor']
[u'Jeffery Taylor']
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207827/discussion-on-answer-by-dabingsou-extract-text-between-two-ps).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way but you can try :

```
file = open(File_Path,'r') #open my file ( be careful with encoding)
text = file.readlines() #extract the content of the file
file.close() #close my file
Goal = [] # will include all the lines beetwen Executives and Analysts 
for indice,line in enumerate(text): 
    if "<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>" in line:
        """
        when the line with "<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>" is found, it will add to Goal all the next line until <p><strong>Analysts</strong></p> appear in a line
        """
        i = 1
        while not("<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>" in text[indice+i]):
            Goal.append(text[indice+i])
            i +=1
        break
print(Goal)
```

the most important part is in the main loop so you can adapt it to your programm

if you know the number of lines beetween Executives and Analysts you can replace the while loop by:

```
Goal = text[indice+1:indice+<number_of_line + 1>]
```

and remove : i = 1

With this way you keep the marker ( like: < p >  ... < /p >) and the "\n" in all your lines

You can remove all the "\n" in a line with a builtin function:

```
line = line.replace("\n","")
```

There are few ways to get data beetween markers like using handle_data in htmlparser or you can use the findall function in re :

```
data_in_line = re.findall(r'>(.*?)<',line)
```

data_in_line will be a list of all the data which respect the pattern r'>(.*?)<' so all the data beetween '>' and '<'

To take an example : '< p > atest< /p >'

it will return [' atest']

Was it helpful to you?

Comment: thanks, but how could i encorporate this in to my current (multiple htmls) code?

Answer (score 0):

@dabingsou has a good solution however here is a much simplified approach without having to use complex repositories:

```
from re import search

html = """<div class="content_part hid" id="article_participants">
<p>Wabash National Corporation (NYSE:<a title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/wnc">WNC</a>)</p><p>Q4 2014 <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: yellow;">Earnings</span> Conference <span class="transcript-search-span" style="background-color: rgb(243, 134, 134);">Call</span></p><p>February 04, 2015 10:00 AM ET</p>
<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Mike Pettit - Vice President of Finance and Investor Relations</p>
<p>Richard Giromini - President and Chief Executive Officer</p>
<p>Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</p>
<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>"""

soup = search( r"(<strong>Executives(.+))<strong>", html, re.DOTALL)
print ( soup.group(1) )
```

Result (html):

```
<strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Mike Pettit - Vice President of Finance and Investor Relations</p>
<p>Richard Giromini - President and Chief Executive Officer</p>
<p>Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</p>
<p>
```

Result (text):

```
print ( bs(soup.group(1), "lxml").get_text() )

Executives
Mike Pettit - Vice President of Finance and Investor Relations
Richard Giromini - President and Chief Executive Officer
Jeffery Taylor - Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer
```

Comment: thanks, but i get the error "name 'search' is not defined", what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Jose, try: from re import search (it's re.search)